# Nodejs mongoose- distinct with sort

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am trying to get messages from unique chat rooms. With this query:

```
message.distinct( "chat_room",{ chat_room: {$regex : ".*" + email + ".*"}} )
```

I get only the list of unique chat rooms but I want to get all information from given collections (like time, id, etc.). What is more when I add:

```
.sort({ time: 1 })
```

I'm getting an error.

Comment: As per [mongoose docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-sort) `sort` cannot be used with `distinct()`. You can workaround using [aggregate](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) to sort grouped values

Comment: Could you support me with the code?

Comment: Sorted it out. Thanks

Comment: Can you kindly post your answer for others

Comment: I used code posted by Vignesh, but added lines like "text: { $last: "$text" }," in group argument.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of distinct you can use aggragate because sort and distinct cant be used at the same time it might throw an error that `cannot sort with distinct`

so what you need to do is

```
message.aggregate([{
           "$match":{ chat_room: {$regex : ".*" + email + ".*"}}
 },{
    $group:{_id:$chat_room}
    },{$sort:{
            'sort_field_name':-1
           }
       }])
```

Comment: I'm getting an error in this part: $group:{_id:$chat_room}

Comment: Fixed that. Changed $chat_room to '$chat_room'. The problem is it doesn't give the output which I need. It just returns names of the rooms. What I need are the most recent messages (based on time variable) with all the information (not only char_rooms names), from different  chat_rooms.

Comment: Sorted it out with $last